# Is a net immune to all damage except slashing?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons

The description of a net says that you can destroy it by dealing 5 points of slashing damage to it (AC 10).

Is it therefore impossible to damage it with other damage types (forcing a creature without slashing damage input that wants to get rid of the net to only use its action to make a DC 10 Strength check) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### It's not immune to ALL damage except slashing

There are a couple of RAW ways to destroy a net:

1. Dealing 5 points of slashing damage.
2. A caster using a fire based spell which states it ignites flammable objects.A net has no protection against fire and would thus be destroyed.
3. A disintegrate spell targetting the net since disintegrate turns objects it strikes into dust.
4. A wish spell.
5. And many other magical solution for which the spell would appropriately remove the net.

But as for using bludgeoning or piercing weapons, the answer is no. The net text specifically states that slashing is the required damage type. And yes, if a creature lacks slashing damage or some other logical way of removing the net such as breathing fire on it, then it would need to rip itself free with the strength check.

The DMG pp. 249-250 has the statistics on object health and AC values, indicating that the net is made of either cloth, paper or rope, and is designated as fragile. If it were made of metal, the AC would be around 19 as that's where iron/steel starts out.

Comment: Are we sure that a net is a flammable object ? Could be a metallic net.

Comment: I'm sure, I added the DMG page and description for objects AC and health values. The net is definitely not metal.

Comment: Still, several fire based spells only ignite flammable objects not being worn. When you're restrained by a net, I'd say you're (unwillingly) wearing it. But that is subject to interpretation. Your Disintegrate point is (I believe) valid, but having an enemy waste a 6th level slot just to remove a net is hilarious.

Comment: I disagree with the first point entirely. Worn objects are simply what your character normally dons because in 5e, unless it says otherwise, items have no damage invulnerabilities other than the general invulnerability to poison and psychic. Basically, a net restraining you isn't worn, it's an object. Much like ropes tying you to a mast, or manacles binding your hands. After all, where's the epic escape when you're about to be hung and your wizard buddy lets loose a scorching ray at the rope, only to discover it's worn and thus inexplicably immune to fire damage suddenly.

Comment: I now agree with you on disagreeing with past me. So a net is indeed vulnerable to an "igniter" spell. Your answer seems valid on all accords.

Comment: It will be very helpful if you include the health and AC of net (common and metallic one) if you didn't manage to deal 5 slashing dmg at once

Comment: @Vylix - That sounds like an interesting question you could ask. Something like, "Does a rope net have a different HP value than a chain link net?" Frankly, I don't think so because the description of a net omits what it's made of, but I also have some DMG references that permit for a creative magical net that has an odd substance minor property that could alter it significantly. Unless stated otherwise though, the 5 damage slashing still gets you out of the net although nothing says it has to be done all at once.